# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when calling vuRenderControllerUpdateVideoBackgroundTexture

Tags: ios, objective-c, vuforia

I receive a EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address = 0x0) when I call the function `vuRenderControllerUpdateVideoBackgroundTexture` in Vuforia 10.

None of the parameters I sent are `NULL`/`nullptr` though.

```objectivec
- (void)renderFrame {
    if(![[self session]cameraIsStarted]) {
        [[self view]setHidden:YES];
        return;
    }
    [[self view]setHidden:NO];
    CAMetalLayer* layer = (CAMetalLayer*) view.layer;

    if(!_videoTexture) {
        [self viewDidChangeSize:[layer drawableSize]];
    }
    
    id<CAMetalDrawable> drawable = [layer nextDrawable];
    if(!drawable) {
        return;
    }
    VuState* state = nullptr;
    vuEngineAcquireLatestState([session engine], &state);
    if(vuStateHasCameraFrame(state) == VU_FALSE) {
        vuStateRelease(state);
        return;
    }
    id<MTLCommandBuffer> commandBuffer = [[self commandQueue] commandBuffer];
    MTLRenderPassDescriptor* backgroundPassDescriptor = [[MTLRenderPassDescriptor alloc] init];
    MTLRenderPassColorAttachmentDescriptor* colorAttachment = [backgroundPassDescriptor colorAttachments][0];
    [colorAttachment setTexture:[drawable texture]];
    [colorAttachment setLoadAction:MTLLoadActionClear];
    [colorAttachment setClearColor:MTLClearColorMake(0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0)];
    [colorAttachment setStoreAction:MTLStoreActionStore];
    [[backgroundPassDescriptor depthAttachment] setTexture:[self videoDepthTexture]];
    [[backgroundPassDescriptor depthAttachment]setLoadAction:MTLLoadActionClear];
    [[backgroundPassDescriptor depthAttachment]setStoreAction:MTLStoreActionStore];
    [[backgroundPassDescriptor depthAttachment]setClearDepth:0.0f];
    id<MTLRenderCommandEncoder> backgroundEncoder = [commandBuffer renderCommandEncoderWithDescriptor:backgroundPassDescriptor];
    int textureUnitData = 0;
    VuRenderVideoBackgroundData backgroundData;
    backgroundData.renderData =  &backgroundEncoder;
    backgroundData.textureUnitData = &textureUnitData;
    backgroundData.textureData = &_videoTexture;
    VuResult result = vuRenderControllerUpdateVideoBackgroundTexture([session renderController], state, &backgroundData); // crash here
```

At the call site, the variables are like this:
[image]

Am I missing an undocumented precondition?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Vuforia so I'm not sure if this will help.

The `OxO` is indeed likely to be a NULL pointer deference.

I dont see the contents of `state` on your image. Did you make sure `state` is not NULL anymore?

Else maybe check if there are methods to instantiate `VuState` and `VuRenderVideoBackgroundData` objects. Sometimes only declaring can be not enough.